# Lucene regex query

Tags: lucene

Using `(.*apple.*)`, I'm currently getting all strings that contain the word 'apple'.

Now, I want to search for strings that contain 'apple' but not the word 'orange'. I've looked through the lucene documentation, and such, and have tried:
`(.*apple.*)(^.*orange.*)`,`(.*apple.*)(.*orange^.*)`and other variations.

Nothing seems to work. How do I get strings that contain one string, but not another?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a **boolean query** for this.

Assuming you have two separate Lucene query objects - one for your `apple` regex search and one for your `orange` regex search (ignoring the "NOT" aspect for now), you can combine those into a Lucene boolean query:

```
import org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery;
import org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanClause;

...

Query query = new BooleanQuery.Builder()
        .add(appleQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)
        .add(orangeQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST_NOT)
        .build();
```

If you prefer to use the **query parser syntax**, you can see examples [documented here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_3_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#NOT). In that case you can use the `NOT` operator or the `-` (prohibit) operator.